# unable to install packages with conda "CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url"

Tags: python, package, conda

I've been trying to unstall python packages with conda but it doesn't seem to work, I get the following message everytime :

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -
An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.
'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'**
```

Please could anyone help me solve this.

Comment: Are you in some kind of restricted network? I.e. corporate or institution?

Comment: Yes that's the case

Comment: You're going to need to contact whoever at your company is responsible for managing the corporate network